# Can I send a different email for a paid submission vs an unpaid/declined submission?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to create a Cognito payment form and I would like to send out a different email (with a corresponding unique mail merge attachment) for a completed payment vs an incomplete/unpaid submission.

While I realize that I can install an approval gate, I would much prefer this to be an automated process because otherwise it could be up to 48 + hrs before I am able to approve everything (depending on the numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can set up two conditional emails to go out, one if the payment is being made online (via the form) and a different email if the user will be paying via cash or check.

Both of these emails can be set up in the [Email Notification](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails) area of Submission Settings. You can have both emails target a Choice field that is asking how the user will be paying.

Cognito Forms will not send out any email until the form has been submitted, and if payment is being collected on the form, a form must complete payment before it can be submitted.

There is not a way to have an incomplete/unpaid submission when you are collecting payment with a Cognito Form.

Comment: Thank you by unpaid sumbission I actually meant decined but I used the zapier integration to find a work around.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response/help. My forms are still very much under development so this should have been obvious to me had i put them through a trial run. which incidentally is what i'm doing now :)